# How to replace website logo on a Domino Server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I would like to know how easy it is to replace an image on a Domino Server.
The link of the website is in this format : https://www.name.com/index.nsf
And I want to change the logo, is it possible to change with a FTP software, or is it difficult to do this. Because the person I request to do this told me that it will take 2 or 3 hours to do this. As I am not used to work with this king of server I prefer to request you advises. Usually, when I use FTP server, I go to the images directory and I replace the image really quickly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's a pretty broad question.  We'd have to know where the image is stored (is it a database resource, or embedded on a form or a page?)  Is image stored in the database or is it referred to by an <img src> link?  Or are you talking about the favicon.ico?

Answer (score 1):

Logo?  Are you referring to the favicon image that shows up in the browser address bar?  If so, then you can place a 16x16px image in the \domino\html folder if you want the image to be the same for all databases on the server.  If you only want it to be changed for that specific database, then you'll need to make a change to the HTML Head content section to refer to the image you want to use. You can either post it in the database or in the folder I referenced before.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="newicon.ico">
```

If you're only wanting to update the one database, then it will take more than a few minutes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult for an image in a database either. More details required.